# Wikibase installation Trouble

Tags: installation, version, wikibase

During installing Wikibase based on the guideline (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Installation), the following error was occurred. As I know, Wikibase 1.37 is not released yet. Any there any solutions?

$php maintenance/update.php

'''
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ExtensionDependencyError: WikibaseRepository is not compatible with the current MediaWiki core (version 1.36.2), it requires: >= 1.37.
in /usr/local/var/www/w/includes/registration/ExtensionRegistry.php:406
'''
Thanks in advance.
H.L

Comment: You need to use the version of Wikibase that corresponds to your version of MediaWiki.
If you are using git, use the REL1_36 branch.